# Switching to a particular tab in VIM

Tags: vim, tabs

I was trying to switch from a tab to another tab (which may not be adjacent to the previous tab) in VIM. Is there any shortcut for that, like we have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> for switching to adjacent tabs?

Also, I was trying to write a key mapping which will give a variable as input to a function and do the operation. For instance, let's say I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> and a function (written by the user) will be called and given as input 5, and the cursor will go to tab 5 (if there is any 5th tab opened).

Can you please suggest how this can be done?

Comment: This should be split into two seperate questions, so you can accept two seperate answers for the two distinct questions.

Comment: @James, to know whether this is for two questions, one should know whether a built-in function for switching to N-th tab exists. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But how one can write a function which accepts a variable input. 

writing

nmap tt <ESC>:tabnew<CR> seems easy 

but how binding :tabnew x (where x is a variable) to a key can be done?

Comment: :tabnew 4 creates a tab named "4"

Comment: @Antony Hatchkins, :tabnew doesn't accept any params - it simply creates tabs. To allow naming you should use tabline and guitablabel.

Comment: @Victor Farazdagi, :tabnew accepts the following params: "[++opt] [+cmd] {file}". Yes, "4" will be the name of the new empty unsaved file, rather than the name of the tab itself.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

use `5gt` to switch to tab 5

> :tabn[ext] {count}
>
> {count}gt
>
> Go to tab page {count}.  The first tab page has number one.

you can also bind it to a key:

```
:map <C-5> 5gt
:imap <C-5> <C-O>5gt
```

(Mapping `Ctrl-<number>` could be different/impossible for some terminals. Consider `Alt-<number>` then)

Comment: Be **VERY** careful not to mix up `:tabnext` and `tabNext`

Comment: `:tabnext`= next tab; `:tabNext` = previous tab

Answer (score 21):

Tackling only your first question, and quoting from `help tabs` in vim:

```
{count}gt       Go to tab page {count}.  The first tab page has number one.
{count}gT       Go {count} tab pages back.  Wraps around from the first one
                to the last one.
```

ie, typing `3gt` goes to the third tab, `3gT` goes 3 tabs back from the current tab.

Comment: To make `3gt` move to the third tab, do `nnoremap gt :normal! gt<CR>`

Comment: I'd dare to say that `{count}gt` works in an absolutely non-Vim way (whereas `{count}gT` does).

Answer (score 5):

Just for sharing the key mapping  to jump into particular tab directly. Please put them into _vimrc and make it work.

```
" Jump to particular tab directly
"NORMAL mode bindings for gvim
noremap <unique> <M-1> 1gt
noremap <unique> <M-2> 2gt
noremap <unique> <M-3> 3gt
noremap <unique> <M-4> 4gt
noremap <unique> <M-5> 5gt
noremap <unique> <M-6> 6gt
noremap <unique> <M-7> 7gt
noremap <unique> <M-8> 8gt
noremap <unique> <M-9> 9gt
noremap <unique> <M-0> 10gt

"INSERT mode bindings for gvim
inoremap <unique> <M-1> <C-O>1gt
inoremap <unique> <M-2> <C-O>2gt
inoremap <unique> <M-3> <C-O>3gt
inoremap <unique> <M-4> <C-O>4gt
inoremap <unique> <M-5> <C-O>5gt
inoremap <unique> <M-6> <C-O>6gt
inoremap <unique> <M-7> <C-O>7gt
inoremap <unique> <M-8> <C-O>8gt
inoremap <unique> <M-9> <C-O>9gt
inoremap <unique> <M-0> <C-O>10gt
```